Unable to get cookies at http://127.0.0.1:3000/ in firefox extension
I don't get any cookies from my ruby on rails development site on firefox with my extension. I already added the extension's id to my CORS policy.
main.js
browser.cookies.getAll({ url: "http://127.0.0.1:3000" }).then(console.log, console.error)

manifest.json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Example Name",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Description",
  "permissions": [
    "cookies",
    "*://127.0.0.1:3000/*"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "main.js"
    ]
  }
}

cookies

output: []

When you load the extension, given the manifest you specify, you should get a warning that the host permission must match the (obsolete) regex:
^(https?|wss?|file|ftp|\*):\/\/(\*|\*\.[^*/]+|[^*/]+)\/.*$/
(It's an obsolete message, because ftp hasn't been supported for a while. There might be other problems with it, too.) Since the host permission request doesn't match the pattern, that permission request is ignored. In other words, don't include the port.
  ...
  "permissions": [
    "cookies",
    "*://127.0.0.1/*"
  ],
  ...

Similarly remove the port from the url value in the details object. The details object is intended to filter cookies in the cookie store. I'd also recommend adding a few values to the details object to make sure that you're not excluding cookies in the store that might otherwise match.
browser.cookies.getAll( {
  firstPartyDomain: null,
  partitionKey: {},
  url: "http://127.0.0.1/*"
} ).then( console.log, console.error );

Be aware that:

"127.0.0.1" has to be the hostname to match. If you use "localhost" in the URL bar, it won't match (which is probably fine for testing); and
getAll call only gets "all" the cookies in the default store ('firefox-default', i.e., not a private window and not a contextual identity).

